# drag and drop icons on datagridview control

Tags: vb.net

I got a couple of icons on my datagridview in 2 image columns, and I would like to change their status(ex: on to off) by draging and droping a buttons with ON and OFF images from a taskbar, any example on how to do this ? appreciated

thaks dan

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a toggled image button in the datagrid. Just click so that it toggles between on an off. No need for drag and drop.

Standard asp:imagebutton with its imageURL bound to a value that formats to Yes.gif or No.gif.  Use the RowCommand event of the datagrid to handle a click of the imagebutton. Find out what the senders image is and swap from Yes to No and visversa.

Comment: sorry I didn't go through all the details in my app, I do have the toggled image button in my datagridview from ON to OFF. the reason I need to drag and drop from a taskbar because I want the user to be able to change the icon image on runtime.

Comment: Yes... so if a user clicks the button... this will fire the RowCommand Event. Find which row was click and then find the button on that row and then swap the image. I have used this sort of interface many times.

Comment: I can swap the image no problem, my issue is with the drag&drop event. on Mouse down what should I be copying ? I can't copy the text of the button because the column type in image

Comment: Sorry, not sure as this would have to be done client side. My suggestion did away with drag and drop and the user would simply just click each of the buttons they needed to change.

Comment: Yeah, I concur with Mych.  Drag and drop in this instance seems clumsy.  How about having a right-click context menu on the gridview instead?